# Laptop display black, unplugging built-in display cable fixes it

Tags: lcd

*I have obtained a 2014 Razer Blade Pro which is not under warranty.*

The display at times will randomly go black when the computer is restarted/shut down. Even the BIOS does not show up.

**Troubleshooting Notes**

- The back lighting still works, I can remote into the computer with RDP and control it
- The HDMI output still works
- Razer support is really useless and provides no documentation, they also charge a $100 inspection fee to even look at the laptop
- **Unplugging and plugging back in the LVDS cable temporarily resolves the issue until it happens again**
- The issue is not consistent and happens at what appears to be random
- Laptop is running Windows 10 64-bit
- I am led to believe it's a hardware related issue, not OS based
- When this issue happens, the computer still sees the display as a built in display

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. I am lost as to what to try at this point to fix the issue. I need it to be dependable for classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this was something to do with the display panel being damaged. Replacing the display(on this laptop is a sealed unit with the cable) fixed it.